# Blender changing Texture Slots while painting

Tags: texture-painting

I've made a shader that layers different textures together so that I can effectively paint materials onto my mesh.

The problem is, when I got to paint on a given layer, for some reason it keeps switching back to a specific layer.

My root layer is rock, so I have no idea why it keeps swapping back to the grass layer. It happens at odd times, like when I move the scene camera or if I let go of the mouse while painting the texture.

What's going on here?

I've recorded a video to show the behavior:
https://youtu.be/hY027iSoa7Q

Answer (score 0):

It seems the switch happens every time the animation playback loops back to beginning. This could be a bug, but I wasn't able to replicate it. I suggest to stop animation playback while painting as a workaround.